# UnsatsifiedLinkError on JSSC Serial Interface (Processing)

Tags: java, eclipse, serial-port, processing

I'm using Proclipsing (processing in Eclipse) but am getting an error when I try and open a port (printing the serial list works fine). I have a feeling some sort of native library is not connected but I'm baffled as to how to do so in Eclipse (and where it link to).

Here's my code:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.serial.Serial;


public class visualization extends PApplet {
    public Serial usb = null;
    public void setup() {
        println(Serial.list());

        println(Serial.list()[5]);


        usb = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[5], 115200);

    }

    public void draw() {
    }
}
```

and the error it throws is:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Ljava/lang/String;Z)J
    at jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Native Method)
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:158)
    at processing.serial.Serial.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at processing.serial.Serial.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at bioauthvisualization3.BioauthVisualization3.setup(BioauthVisualization3.java:15)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while setting up IntelliJ IDEA for development with Processing. But I imagine you can apply the same method in Proclipsing. The solution that worked for me was threefold.

1. I created a global library that contained the Processing and Serial libraries. In OS X the required jar files can be found in the directory `/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java/` and `/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java/modes/libraries/serial/library/`. I added the following libraries: `core.jar`, `serial.jar`and `jssc.jar`.
2. Next I had to add the global library to my module dependencies.
3. The last step was to add the path to the native libraries to the VM options for the appletviewer: `-Djava.library.path="/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java/modes/java/libraries/serial/library/macosx"`

My guess is that Proclipsing does the first two steps for you but you have to add the native libraries to the vm options manually since these depend on the system you're working on. Hope that helps.

I derived the solution for step 3 from [this forum entry](http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/processing-opengl-in-intellij-idea.html).